# How to use d3.js Fisheye on imported SVG

Tags: d3.js

At this moment I've succesfully imported an SVG i want to put a fisheye effect on. I want to do something similar to [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2962761). I've looked at the code used there that looks like:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .attr("d", line);

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  fisheye.center(d3.mouse(this));
  path.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.map(fisheye)); });
});
```

however, i dont use lines as they do but i do have paths like they have. To be honest i'm not quite sure why they use d3.line in this code like this. But what i have now is this:

```
  d3.xml('log.svg')
    .then(data => {

      d3.select('body').node().append(data.documentElement)

      var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular()
        .radius(200)
        .distortion(2);

      var svg = d3.select("body").select("svg g")
      var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .attr("d");

      svg.on("mousemove", function() {
        fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));
        path.attr("d", function(d) {
          return (d.map(fisheye)) // Not sure about this part yet.
        });

      });

    });
```

The console gives me the following error:

---

Uncaught TypeError: path.attr is not a function

---

This happens on this line:

```
path.attr("d", function(d) {
          return (d.map(fisheye)) // Not sure about this part yet.
        });
```

Does anybody know why it's giving this error like this? It's not that much different from the working version is it?

Comment: circular is not a member of fisheye

Comment: When you declare path, drop the line .attr(‘d’);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .attr("d");
```

to

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path");
```

(also note that you sometimes conclude your statements with a semicolon and sometimes not)

---

The reason for this error is important to understand since it is an important code design used a lot in d3.js.

To set properties/attributes/behaviors of objects you can’t set them directly. Instead you call a function setting them, so the inner logic can avoid side effects.

These *setter functions* typically do two more things:

1. They are *getter* functions as well, returning the corresponding **value**
2. **When used as a setter function**, they return the object for which you are setting a value to a property.

The second bullet allows you for the elegant method chaining:

So, if you want to set three properties on an object, you don’t need to write

```
let obj = *object*;
obj.method1(‘a’);
obj.method2(‘b’);
obj.method3(‘c’);
```

or

```
let obj = *object*;
obj = obj.method1(‘a’);
obj = obj.method2(‘b’);
obj = obj.method3(‘c’);
```

you can write instead:

```
let obj = *object*.method1(‘a’).method2(‘b’).method3(‘c’);
```

On *selection* you more often than not apply this method chaining, since you set a lot of properties!

As I mentioned, for convenience, the same method can be used as a *getter* function:

```
// calling method without argument returns its value
obj.method1(); // returns ‚a‘ !! not the obj!!
```

That means after applying a getter function, you cannot do method chaining any more, since ‚a‘ doesn’t have a *method2*, etc.

With *selections* the same code design applies, except the method *selection.attr()* or *selection.style()* decides to be a **setter**/**getter** based on the second parameter.

Coming back to your example:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .attr("d");
```

is the getter function, returning the string which is (or has not been) assigned to the ‚d‘ attribute of the  element

Instead:

```
 var path = svg.selectAll("path");
```

returns the *selection* of all *path*s and so would the
 **setter** function:

```
    var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .attr("d", „*your path string*“);
```

Note that the implementation of this code design with **getter, setter and method chaining** you see in your fisheye example itself:

```
fisheye.center = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return center;
  center = _;
  return fisheye;
};

return rescale();
```

See also [Mike Bostocks excellent article](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) on reusable code where he explains this code design.

Comment: Thank you! This has given me much more insight into what I'm doing.

Now the challenge begins of changing the path data, cause when i do
   
   `path.attr("d", function(d) {
          return (d.map(fisheye)) // Not sure about this part yet.
        });`


It tells me d is undefined, could this have to do with that I'm working in the promise of the svg?

Comment: The d in the callback function refers to the data which is joined to the selection. To use you that ‚d‘ you must have attached data to the selection of path elements or the parents thereof. I don’t see that in your code - that’s why d is undefined. Attaching data to selection is a core concept in d3.js - it is called data join - you should google it . It typically looks like: selection.data(...).enter(...).append(...). Like at the original fisheye example for the data joins!

Comment: Ok thank you, I knew that, but I expected, that since the path data is already present in the SVG, it would translate over to the selection.

Comment: Depending on what you want you may not need a data join. You may also drop the .node() part, since you want to append to a selection not to an element.